How to prove a property of the product of Eisenstein Series
I want to prove that, if $$ E_i(\tau) = \frac{1}{2\zeta(2i)}\sum_{(m,n)\in\mathbb{Z}^2-\{(0,0)\}}(m\tau+n)^{-k}$$
is the normalized Eisenstein Series of weight $i$, then $E_i(\tau)E_j(\tau)\neq E_{i+j}(\tau)$ whenever $\dim \mathcal{M}_{i+j}(SL_2(\mathbb{Z}))>1$, where $\mathcal{M}_{k}(SL_2(\mathbb{Z}))$ is the vector space of modular forms of weight $k$ over $\mathbb{C}$.
I know that you can expand the vector space as
$$\mathcal{M}_{k}=\mathbb{C}E_k \oplus S_k$$
where $E_k$ is the vector space of the Eisenstein Series of weight $k$ over $\mathbb{C}$, and $S_k$ is the vector space of cusp forms over $\mathbb{C}$. Also, $\dim \mathbb{C}E_k = 1$ so $\dim \mathcal{M}_{k}>1$ implies $\dim S_k > 0$.That means that $E_iE_j = E_{i+j}+s(\tau)$ where $s$ is some cusp form, but I'm not sure how to prove that $s(\tau)\neq 0$. Any help would be appreciated.

There is a "highbrow" proof using the Rankin--Selberg integral formula to show that if $f$ is a cuspidal eigenform of weight $k = i + j$, then $\langle f, E_i E_j\rangle$ is a product of values of the $L$-function of $f$, and these are non-zero since they are in the domain of convergence of the Euler product. Hence $E_i E_j$ has non-zero projection to every cuspidal eigenspace. You can find this argument (generalised to any level $N\ge 1$) in Borisov--Gunnells, for example. However, your question asks for a weaker statement, which should probably have an easier proof.
